# Why does this Rust + Apple Metal GPGPU SHA256 compute kernel code perform worse than CPU and much worse than GPU-accelerated hashcat?

Tags: rust, gpu, gpgpu, metal, sha

Hashcat results:

```
---------------------------
* Hash-Mode 1400 (SHA2-256)
---------------------------

Speed.#1.........:   447.2 MH/s (64.33ms) @ Accel:512 Loops:256 Thr:32 Vec:1
```

Rust + Metal GPU results:

```
GPU: After 1000 iterations: 6.1558 MH/s
```

6.1558 MH/s is roughly 72.65 times slower than 447.2 MH/s.

For reference, CPU is about 10.77927 MH/s (meaning GPU is slower than CPU in the Rust/Metal case)

Rust code:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use hex_literal::hex;

use metal::*;
use objc::rc::autoreleasepool;

const PROGRAM: &'static str = include_str!("./kernel.metal");
const SHA256_HASH_SIZE: usize = 32;
const DISPLAY_INTERVAL: usize = 10;

fn run_test(device: &Device, cmd_queue: &CommandQueue, compute_function: &FunctionRef) -> usize {
    return autoreleasepool(|| {
        // parameters
        let num_thread_groups = 32;
        let num_threads_per_thread_group = 512;
        let num_iterations = num_thread_groups * num_threads_per_thread_group;
        let mut inputs: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        let mut input_lengths: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
        for _ in 0..num_iterations {
            let input1 = b"hello1";
            inputs.extend_from_slice(input1);
            input_lengths.push(input1.len() as u32);
        }
        let outputs: Vec<u8> = vec![0; SHA256_HASH_SIZE * num_iterations];
        // encode
        let cmd_buffer = cmd_queue.new_command_buffer();
        let cmd_encoder = cmd_buffer.new_compute_command_encoder();
        let pipeline_state = device.new_compute_pipeline_state_with_function(compute_function).unwrap();
        cmd_encoder.set_compute_pipeline_state(&pipeline_state);
        // input
        let encoded_inputs = {
            device.new_buffer_with_data(
                inputs.as_ptr() as *const _,
                inputs.len() as u64,
                MTLResourceOptions::CPUCacheModeDefaultCache,
            )
        };
        cmd_encoder.set_buffer(0, Some(&encoded_inputs), 0);
        // input lengths
        let encoded_input_lengths = {
            device.new_buffer_with_data(
                input_lengths.as_ptr()  as *const _,
                (input_lengths.len() * std::mem::size_of::<u32>()) as u64,
                MTLResourceOptions::CPUCacheModeDefaultCache,
            )
        };
        cmd_encoder.set_buffer(1, Some(&encoded_input_lengths), 0);
        // output
        let encoded_outputs = {
            device.new_buffer_with_data(
                outputs.as_ptr() as *const _,
                outputs.len() as u64,
                MTLResourceOptions::CPUCacheModeDefaultCache,
            )
        };
        cmd_encoder.set_buffer(2, Some(&encoded_outputs), 0);
        // dispatch
        cmd_encoder.dispatch_thread_groups(
            MTLSize {
                width: num_thread_groups as u64,
                height: 1,
                depth: 1,
            },
            MTLSize {
                width: num_threads_per_thread_group as u64,
                height: 1,
                depth: 1,
            },
        );
        cmd_encoder.end_encoding();
        cmd_buffer.commit();
        cmd_buffer.wait_until_completed();
        // validate
        let encoded_outputs_contents_ptr = encoded_outputs.contents() as *mut u8;
        for i in 0..num_iterations {
            let hash_ptr = unsafe { encoded_outputs_contents_ptr.add(i * SHA256_HASH_SIZE) }; 
            let hash_slice = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(hash_ptr, SHA256_HASH_SIZE) };
            assert_eq!(hash_slice[..], hex!("91e9240f415223982edc345532630710e94a7f52cd5f48f5ee1afc555078f0ab"));
        }
        // return
        return num_iterations;
    });
}

fn main() {
    // benchmark stats
    let mut total_hashes = 0;
    let mut total_elapsed = Duration::new(0, 0);
    let mut num_iterations = 0;
    // device
    let devices = Device::all();
    let device = devices.iter().find(|device| device.name() == "Apple M1").unwrap();
    // library
    let library_compile_options = CompileOptions::new();
    library_compile_options.set_fast_math_enabled(true);
    let library = device.new_library_with_source(PROGRAM, &library_compile_options).unwrap();
    // kernel function
    let kernel_function = library.get_function("sha256_kernel", None).unwrap();
    // command queue
    let cmd_queue = device.new_command_queue();
    // pipeline
    let pipeline_state_descriptor = ComputePipelineDescriptor::new();
    pipeline_state_descriptor.set_thread_group_size_is_multiple_of_thread_execution_width(true);
    pipeline_state_descriptor.set_compute_function(Some(&kernel_function));
    // compute function
    let compute_function = pipeline_state_descriptor.compute_function().unwrap();
    // loop
    loop {
        let start = std::time::Instant::now();
        let num_hashes = run_test(&device, &cmd_queue, compute_function);
        let elapsed = start.elapsed();
        total_hashes += num_hashes;
        total_elapsed += elapsed;
        num_iterations += 1;
        if num_iterations % DISPLAY_INTERVAL == 0 {
            let hashes_per_second = (total_hashes as f64 / total_elapsed.as_secs_f64()) / 1000000.0;
            println!(
                "GPU: After {} iterations: {:.5} MH/s",
                num_iterations, hashes_per_second
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Metal code:

```c
// code is from https://github.com/ilvn/SHA256

#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

#define NULL nullptr

constant const uint32_t K[64] = {
    0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
    0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
    0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
    0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
    0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
    0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
    0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
    0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
    0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
    0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
    0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
    0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
    0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
    0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
    0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
    0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
};

struct sha256_context {
    uint8_t  buf[64];
    uint32_t hash[8];
    uint32_t bits[2];
    uint32_t len;
    uint32_t rfu__;
    uint32_t W[64];
};

#define _shb(x, n) ((x >> (n & 31)) & 0xff)
#define _shw(x, n) ((x << (n & 31)) & 0xffffffff)
#define _r(x, n) ((x >> n) | _shw(x, 32 - n))
#define _Ch(x, y, z) ((x & y) ^ ((~x) & z))
#define _Ma(x, y, z) ((x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ (y & z))
#define _S0(x) (_r(x, 2) ^ _r(x, 13) ^ _r(x, 22))
#define _S1(x) (_r(x, 6) ^ _r(x, 11) ^ _r(x, 25))
#define _G0(x) (_r(x, 7) ^ _r(x, 18) ^ (x >> 3))
#define _G1(x) (_r(x, 17) ^ _r(x, 19) ^ (x >> 10))
#define _word(c) (_shw((c)[0], 24) | _shw((c)[1], 16) | _shw((c)[2], 8) | ((c)[3]))
#define _addbits(ctx, n)                                 \
    do {                                                 \
        if ((ctx)->bits[0] > (0xffffffff - (n))) {       \
            (ctx)->bits[1] = ((ctx)->bits[1] + 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF; \
        }                                                \
        (ctx)->bits[0] = ((ctx)->bits[0] + (n)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;   \
    } while(0)
    
void _hash(thread sha256_context *ctx)
{
    uint32_t a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    uint32_t t[2];

    a = ctx->hash[0];
    b = ctx->hash[1];
    c = ctx->hash[2];
    d = ctx->hash[3];
    e = ctx->hash[4];
    f = ctx->hash[5];
    g = ctx->hash[6];
    h = ctx->hash[7];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (i < 16) {
            ctx->W[i] = _word((&ctx->buf[_shw(i, 2)]));
        } else {
            ctx->W[i] = _G1(ctx->W[i - 2])  + ctx->W[i - 7] +
                        _G0(ctx->W[i - 15]) + ctx->W[i - 16];
        }

        t[0] = h + _S1(e) + _Ch(e, f, g) + K[i] + ctx->W[i];
        t[1] = _S0(a) + _Ma(a, b, c);
        h = g;
        g = f;
        f = e;
        e = d + t[0];
        d = c;
        c = b;
        b = a;
        a = t[0] + t[1];
    }

    ctx->hash[0] += a;
    ctx->hash[1] += b;
    ctx->hash[2] += c;
    ctx->hash[3] += d;
    ctx->hash[4] += e;
    ctx->hash[5] += f;
    ctx->hash[6] += g;
    ctx->hash[7] += h;
} // _hash

void sha256_init(thread sha256_context *ctx)
{
    if (ctx != NULL) {
        ctx->bits[0] = ctx->bits[1] = ctx->len = 0;
        ctx->hash[0] = 0x6a09e667;
        ctx->hash[1] = 0xbb67ae85;
        ctx->hash[2] = 0x3c6ef372;
        ctx->hash[3] = 0xa54ff53a;
        ctx->hash[4] = 0x510e527f;
        ctx->hash[5] = 0x9b05688c;
        ctx->hash[6] = 0x1f83d9ab;
        ctx->hash[7] = 0x5be0cd19;
    }
} // sha256_init

void sha256_hash(thread sha256_context *ctx, const thread uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
    const thread uint8_t *bytes = (const thread uint8_t *)data;

    if ((ctx != NULL) && (bytes != NULL) && (ctx->len < sizeof(ctx->buf))) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ctx->buf[ctx->len++] = bytes[i];
            if (ctx->len == sizeof(ctx->buf)) {
                _hash(ctx);
                _addbits(ctx, sizeof(ctx->buf) * 8);
                ctx->len = 0;
            }
        }
    }
} // sha256_hash

void sha256_done(thread sha256_context *ctx, thread uint8_t *output)
{
    uint32_t i, j;

    if (ctx != NULL) {
        j = ctx->len % sizeof(ctx->buf);
        ctx->buf[j] = 0x80;
        for (i = j + 1; i < sizeof(ctx->buf); i++) {
            ctx->buf[i] = 0x00;
        }

        if (ctx->len > 55) {
            _hash(ctx);
            for (j = 0; j < sizeof(ctx->buf); j++) {
                ctx->buf[j] = 0x00;
            }
        }

        _addbits(ctx, ctx->len * 8);
        ctx->buf[63] = _shb(ctx->bits[0],  0);
        ctx->buf[62] = _shb(ctx->bits[0],  8);
        ctx->buf[61] = _shb(ctx->bits[0], 16);
        ctx->buf[60] = _shb(ctx->bits[0], 24);
        ctx->buf[59] = _shb(ctx->bits[1],  0);
        ctx->buf[58] = _shb(ctx->bits[1],  8);
        ctx->buf[57] = _shb(ctx->bits[1], 16);
        ctx->buf[56] = _shb(ctx->bits[1], 24);
        _hash(ctx);

        if (output != NULL) {
            for (i = 0, j = 24; i < 4; i++, j -= 8) {
                output[i +  0] = _shb(ctx->hash[0], j);
                output[i +  4] = _shb(ctx->hash[1], j);
                output[i +  8] = _shb(ctx->hash[2], j);
                output[i + 12] = _shb(ctx->hash[3], j);
                output[i + 16] = _shb(ctx->hash[4], j);
                output[i + 20] = _shb(ctx->hash[5], j);
                output[i + 24] = _shb(ctx->hash[6], j);
                output[i + 28] = _shb(ctx->hash[7], j);
            }
        }
    }
} // sha256_done

void sha256(thread sha256_context *ctx, const thread uint8_t *input, size_t len, thread uint8_t *output)
{
    sha256_init(ctx);
    sha256_hash(ctx, input, len);
    sha256_done(ctx, output);
} // sha256

kernel void sha256_kernel(device uint8_t *inputs [[ buffer(0) ]],
                          device uint32_t *input_lengths [[ buffer(1) ]],
                          device uint8_t *outputs [[ buffer(2) ]],
                          uint threadgroup_position_in_grid [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]],
                          uint thread_position_in_grid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]],
                          uint thread_position_in_threadgroup [[ thread_position_in_threadgroup ]],
                          uint threads_per_threadgroup [[ threads_per_threadgroup ]])
{
    // calculate input_start based on thread_position_in_grid
    uint32_t input_start = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < thread_position_in_grid; i++) {
        input_start += input_lengths[i]; 
    }
    // calculate output_start based on thread_position_in_grid
    uint32_t output_start = thread_position_in_grid * 32;
    // device variables
    device uint8_t *device_input = inputs + input_start;
    device uint8_t *device_output = outputs + output_start;
    uint32_t input_length = input_lengths[thread_position_in_grid];
    // thread local variables
    thread sha256_context ctx;
    thread uint8_t thread_output[32];
    thread uint8_t thread_input[256];
    // check input length
    if (input_length > 256) {
        // TODO: freak out
        return;
    }
    // copy device input to thread input
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < input_length; i++) {
        thread_input[i] = device_input[i];
    }
    // call hash
    sha256(&ctx, thread_input, input_length, thread_output);
    // copy thread output to device output
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        device_output[i] = thread_output[i];
    }
}
```

I've tried all sorts of different combinations of num_thread_groups / num_threads_per_thread_group to try to combat the overhead related to orchestrating CPU -> GPU and back. I also tried having each "GPU thread" hash more than 1 just input (I tried thread chunk sizes of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. 1 was always best).

I can't seem to beat the CPU, let alone come close to hashcat performance.

Comment: You are measuring total CPU time it takes to complete the command buffer. That also includes copying the data you are gonna hash into a new buffer. And even more surprisingly, compiling the pipeline itself. If you want to know the real run time on the GPU, which is probably more representative, you can use `gpuEndTime - gpuStartTime` on the command buffer.

Comment: You are also measuring validation as part of your run time

Comment: @JustSomeGuy unless we know for sure that HashCat's benchmark for SHA2-256 isn't doing that, is that really the issue? I will admit, when I just hash the same string over and over again with no passing input device -> host and having each kernel thread figure out what to do, performance goes up but... is that really useful?

Comment: I mean, that’s just a bad benchmark. Yes, what you are interested in is hashing a string, but you have to design for it to be fast on GPU. Otherwise, you could just use CPU as well.

Comment: Also, you aren't really counting megahashes per second this way, you are counting how long it takes to hash one thing of a given size.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying that the hashcat benchmark is most likely just figuring out raw hashrate of 1 string over and over again, and not actually technically how many hashes it could copy CPU -> GPU, hash, then GPU -> CPU?

Comment: I have no idea what hashcat benchmark is doing, but the way you are testing it, you are not measuring megahashes per second, because the overhead of creating buffers, building pipelines, filling out the buffers and GPU scheduling is going to be significant on a small-ish workload.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy how can i simulate a “non small-ish” workload? i thought i was simulating the largest workload i could